# Is it possible to uninstall a particular component in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I know that we can selectively install files via [COMPONENT in install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) as shown in the minimal example below

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(example)

install(
  FILES a.h
  DESTINATION include
  COMPONENT groupA)

install(
  FILES b.h
  DESTINATION include
  COMPONENT groupB)

add_custom_target(
  installA COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT=groupA -P
                   "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake")
```

However, is there a way to just remove the files that are installed via `installA`? Something like

```
add_custom_target(
  uninstallA COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -DCMAKE_UNINSTALL_COMPONENT=groupA -P
                     "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_install.cmake")
```

doesn't exist. The official way of [uninstall](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/FAQ#can-i-do-make-uninstall-with-cmake) will remove all files, but I only want the files in `groupA` removed. Another angle to look at it is that, is there a way to get the list of files installed by `installA`? If there's a way to get the list of files, I can remove it via `file(REMOVE)`.

Comment: "The official way of uninstall" links to a page mentioning that there is no official way of way of uninstalling. In general it's not possible to implement this because of the `install(CODE)` command which could be creating any number of files. Furthermore I assume the `install_manifest.txt` just saves a list of the most recent `cmake --install` run regardless of whether you install everything at once or just some components. If you want uninstall functionality,some of the cpack generators should provide the possibility of per-component packages so getting your package manager involved may help